# How to implement payments in a Flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, square

I am using flutter to build my first ever app.The app is designed for users to be able to buy and sell products amongst each other and I would like to set up functionality to have payments go through the app. There does not seem to be a lot of documentation on this and I really don't know where to start. Can anyone enlighten me of what the easiest route to go down will be? Square? Stripe? Are there any good start to finish tutorials out there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely do this with Square using our In-App Payments SDK! I would suggest taking a look at our example to quickly get started: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/tree/master/example This will show you from start-to-finish how to take a payment from a customer within your Flutter application.

With that said, to comment on how this would behave: Essentially your Flutter application would be able to open a "card entry" screen, which would allow a customer to enter their card details accordingly. The result would be a `nonce`, which you can then easily charge on your backend. The example shows all of this, I just wanted to quickly explain the high-level behavior.

For more information, I suggest taking a look at the [Square Developer Docs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/in-app-payments-sdk/what-it-does) for our In-App Payments SDK. Of course, if you have follow-up questions, don't hesitate to follow-up with us over in our Slack channel: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: @JohnConde why is this classified as an off topic question? Where should I have posted this instead? I apologize if I am not correctly following the guidlines

Comment: It's both too broad and asking for recommendations for resources. Both are off topic here. I suggest you go through the [tour], the [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see what questions are on and off topic, to see how this site works, and to help you improve your future questions.